# Where are the GDAL binaries stored on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, package-management, gdal

I'm trying to make sure GDAL is installed on my system, and the [Download documentation](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries) says that

> Fedora, since release 7, includes GDAL binaries.

Where are those GDAL binaries? Or what's the name of a package GDAL includes that I can search for to find out?

Comment: Are you looking for binaries on Fedora, or on CentOS?

Comment: CentOS. Which is downstream from Fedora, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find out the installed files of a package using this way:

```
rpm -qvpl gdal
```

If you have installed gdal binaries, you will see the installation files and folders. If you haven't, you can install [ELGIS](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Enterprise_Linux_GIS) repo as Stephen said, and then search for it:

```
yum search gdal
```

and then install appropriate packages, using:

```
yum install gdal*
```

and then find out the installation folder.

Comment: It looks like [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) is recommended instead of ELGIS now (according to the page you linked), but this is the best way to install GDAL without going to a third party.

Answer (score 2):

CentOS is based on RHEL, which is itself based on Fedora, but the package selections are different (and while CentOS and RHEL are very similar, there are significant differences between Fedora and RHEL, not least the fact that they have rather different aims).

CentOS [doesn’t include any GDAL package](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/), and [ELGIS](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Enterprise_Linux_GIS) doesn’t support CentOS 7. It turns out [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) now includes GDAL packages for RHEL and CentOS 7:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

will make them available on your system.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I'll have to find binaries from a 3rd party or compile them.